# How to test Amazon S3 or Microsoft Azure?

Tags: android, azure, amazon-s3, azure-storage

I want to upload my files into a cloud storage (Amazon S3 or MS Azure, the first one is more desired) from the app I'm developing, however, I do not have an account to test them (and I cannot create one because I do not have credit card, etc.). 
Is there any way to test them without creating an account on the official sites? (**For example** a local server which runs a version of these cloud services)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about subscription offers / pricing, and not a programming question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I suggest you to read the upvoted answer first, then take your decision. Btw, how do you think it is about subscription offers?! Have you read the question at all?

Comment: That upvoted answer isn't going to solve your problem, as the emulator is not exactly like the real Azure storage (there are functional differences).

Comment: @DavidMakogon I guess the functionality that I need is not pricing anyway! Btw, it is a good answer (thought I'm waiting for a better answer if any), because this emulator is officially released for development (refer to the link please).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Azure, you could have the Azure storage emulator to simulate the Azure storage accounts on local environment without having an Azure subscription.

The Azure storage emulator is part of the Azure SDK installation.
For Azure SDK for .NET, you can download from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/).

Here is also a [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/#storage-emulator-release-notes) on how to use the Azure Storage Emulator for development and testing.

For AWS, there is no way to simulate the S3 storage without an AWS account on local because they do not provide a storage simulator.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. It helps too much. Btw, I guess it would be more useful and complete if you add the link of the place one can find this emulator to your answer.

Comment: I have edited my answer based on your feedback. If you think it's complete please kindly help to mark it as accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is **NO** The thing with amazon is you cant actually get a free account unless you provide your credit card details, Even with the free trial accounts the card is required.But once you do you can try out the most widely used features like
1)**Dynamo DB**
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.JsShell.html
2)**web Services**
https://aws.amazon.com/
3)**S3 file upload**
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html

Answer (score -1):

If you want to try Amazon S3 Storage. You can with a free tier account. The storage is up to 5GB and expires in a year however.

https://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: You will still need a credit card for that case...

Comment: I guess you have not read the question carefully.